# Ubuntu 16.04 not booting after fresh install

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 when I start it shows me

```
Error: no such device. <Alphanumeric character here>
Error: file '/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-59-generic' not found.
Error: you need to load the kernel first
```

I have tried reinstalling it multiple times but the same problem persists.

Update: The problem resolved after I manually partitioned Ubuntu partition by logging into windows partition and then reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04 again.

Comment: 3.19 is the kernel from Trusty Tahr (14.04)  You obviously made an error in the re-install process.  if you have a back-up of your data, follow [this guide](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: This was *not* a fresh install...

Comment: There was 14.04 installed earlier on the same partition, but I selected the format option before starting installation